# Jquery Find a especific Parent

Tags: jquery, parents

Using Jquery, I'd like to know how can I take the text **(Take this text clicking in button (btnId))** between tag
`<h4> </h4>` when I click the button (btnId)? Bcause i got too much
difficult to solve it!

```
<div class = "class1" id = "class1">
    <div class = "class2" id = "class2">

        <div class = "class4" id = "class4">

            <h4 class = "h_reference" id = "h_reference"> Take this text clicking in button (btnId)</h4>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class = "class3" id = "class3">
        <div class = "class5" id = "class5">
            <div class = "class6" id = "class6">

            </div>

            <div class = "class7" id = "class7">
                <div class = "class8" id = "class8">    
                    <div class = "class9" id = "class9">

                    </div>
                    <button id="btnId" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#h_reference').text()` perhaps?  What have you tried and how did that attempt fail?  It seems like any cursory look at jQuery code/examples would solve this for you.

Comment: Having id for all the elements is a bad practice. This will flood your global object `window` by creating reference to all of those elements. Use it sparingly.

Comment: I was giving an example to ilustrate my doubt... so... Thank you very much  for your pont of view. #Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy and #David. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you want to fetch the inner text of a given element on click via jQuery. Here's how:

```
$('#btnId').click(function() {
  var txt = $('#h_reference').text();
  //do what you will with txt here
});
```

This assigns a click handler to the button via jQuery's `$.click` function. That handler reads the text of the `h4` with id `h_reference`. From there, you can do what you want with that text.

Comment: In another way to solve... how can I solve it using parents? An Idea?